# shared pointer of dynamically allocated int array triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, shared-ptr

Thanks in advance for people who help.
I am new to C++. I am learning the concept of smart pointer/shared pointer and using Visual Studio 2013RC. Following the example in wikipedia, I created a shared pointer like this

SharedPointer.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
//using namespace std;
void main(){
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp1(new int(5), std::default_delete<int[]>());
    //std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 = sp1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  sp1.get()[i]= i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) std::cout << sp1.get()[i] << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

The program compiles and prints out 0,1,2,3,4 without any error, but then it comes the window saying "SharedPointer.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

Could anyone tell me what is the reason for this exception?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your `main` function should have a return type of `int`, please.

Comment: A breakpoint is not an exception.

Comment: I think you wanted `new int[5]`, not `new int(5)`.

Comment: @Arkadiy: I think you wanted to write an answer, not a comment

Comment: @Ligthness: too short for an answer :)

Comment: @Arkadiy: No, not at all! Not if it answers the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have used `int[5]` instead of `int(5)` here:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp1(new int[5], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Currently, your code allocates a single `int` which is initialized to `5`, and then it tries to access it as an array of five `int`s (undefined behavior). After that, the smart pointer tries to delete that `int` with a `delete[]` operator (instead of a "plain" `delete` operator) which is also an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`sp1` is destroyed at the end of your program, causing the default deleter to run. The default deleter here invokes `delete[]`, but since you didn't use `new[]`, this is invalid.

In fact, from the looks of things, you meant `new int[5]` rather than `new int(5)`, because you're also attempting to access five elements of this memory block where in fact you only allocated one.